# How to secure password and hash from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, authentication

I have a .NET WPF application.

I create two accounts, one is named "final" will be defined. The password of this account will be defined as "Fnl666". The other account is named "admin" will be defined in this system.

But the admin account password must be kept secret (should never know the admin password). Even my project source code I shouldn't be able to find the password for this admin account in clear text if I look into it. How to solution to this you need to provide?

I have thought to use password asymmetric encryption or hash entered on the login page of the Login will compare the hash database value and compare to the password.

What is your advice?

How to hide the admin password on the login page in .NET and in SQL Server?

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHOtz.jpg)

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs25R.jpg)

[secure password hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp6Wh.png)

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leEMQ.jpg)

Here is my hash algorithm:

```
public static string hashPassword(string password)
{
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] password_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] encrypted_bytes = sha1.ComputeHash(password_bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);
}
```

Here is my login page submit button click

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_Login where @P1=userName and @P2=password", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", hashPassword(TextBox2.Text));

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                if (hashPassword(TextBox2.Text) == ??)
                {
                    Server.Transfer("loginSuccesful.aspx");
                    //Response.Redirect();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Server.Transfer("errorPage.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Server.Transfer("errorPage.aspx");
        }
}
```

Comment: Your password hash is bad. You need to include salt, or just use https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

Comment: I might point out that if the client app has rights to query password hashes directly off the `tbl_Login` table then you're wasting your time anyway, it'll be fairly trivial to get a piece of text that matches that hash. You also need `using` on your connection, command and reader to dispose them, do *not* cache the connection.

Comment: Yeah, if the client can write to the database, assume the user will find a way to hack into the database connection and write a new password hash for a known password. Though you could limit this to some extent by only allowing the user to write changes via a stored procedure. But then you'd have to implement the password hash in a procedure... At best this is "security theatre".

Comment: IF you are hashing the password... you are pretty much set... you need to use better hashing technique though and of course using rand salt unique to each user.

Comment: You should not use `where @P1=userName and @P2=password`. you should first get the user row using `where @P1=userName`. and then hash the user input password and compare it with the user row password hash.

Comment: Hello @Bartu Bozkurt and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider not deleting your questions after you get an answer that works, as questions are meant to teach the entire programming community and there may be other users that may have the same problem as yours in the future and could benefit from your post. Addionally, all of the reputation earned from the post will be deducted once the question is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any type of Application,

**Encryption:**

1. You can hash the password with some strong hashing algorithm (For eg. BCrypt) with a random salt.
2. Then Encrypting the hashed password with some strong encryption algorithms like AES-256 with a user-specific key.
3. In this way, you can strongly hide anyone's password.

**Decryption:**

1. You must decrypt the password first with the current user's key, then you must hash the user entered password again with the same salt(may store salt on the database) and check for the same hashed password with the database and let them into the application.

**Always Encrypted**:
If you again want some protection for the SQL database, you can use Always Encrypted on SSMS to encrypt the sensitive columns of your tables.

I think what I've answered is relevant for you.

Comment: @Bartu Bozkurt, Can you mark it as an answer, if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

We can use MD5 hash technology. MD5 hash generator is useful for encoding passwords. we can use keycode also for more strong hash password

```
    DECLARE @KeyCode VARCHAR(100)='0AC3D55A-5697-4A74-8CEF-4FD6AD82126F';
    DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(10)='Abcd1234'; 
    DECLARE @HassPassword VARCHAR(255)='';

    SELECT @HassPassword=HASHBYTES('MD5',
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),@Password)+CAST(@KeyCode AS NVARCHAR(36)));
   SELECT @HassPassword AS HassPassword;
```

[image]